# Configuring njobs with Python tpot

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, tpot

Can the njobs parameter be configured using tpot within code and not passed as command line parameter ?

Reading https://rhiever.github.io/tpot/using/ states :

```
-njobs  NUM_JOBS    Any positive integer or -1  Number of CPUs for evaluating pipelines in parallel during the TPOT optimization process. 

Assigning this to -1 will use as many cores as available on the computer.
```

But how to configure this parameter within code ?

Trying  :

```
TPOTClassifier(generations=5, verbosity=3,  config_dict='TPOT light' , NUM_JOBS = 4)
```

returns error :

```
TPOTClassifier(generations=5, verbosity=3,  config_dict='TPOT light' , NUM_JOBS = 4)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'NUM_JOBS'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achieved using `n_jobs` parameter:

```py
TPOTClassifier(
    generations=5,
    verbosity=3,
    config_dict='TPOT light',
    n_jobs=4
)
```